Comparison of oxygen and carbon-12 as standards for mass
While studying about the standards of atomic and molecular mass, I have learnt that while initially hydrogen was used as a standard of mass (its mass taken as unity), according to my book, oxygen was adopted as a standard on the account of the following-
(i) It is much easier to obtain compounds of elements with oxygen than with hydrogen as oxygen is more reactive than Hydrogen.
(ii) The atomic masses of most of the elements become approximately whole numbers but with hydrogen as the standard the atomic masses of the most of the numbers are fractional.
While the second point is intelligible, I fail to understand why the reactivity of oxygen has anything to do with it being adopted as a standard, since a century later, the very stable carbon-12 was accepted  as a standard.
My question is, then - how does point (i) hold  as a reason? What was the understanding behind replacing Hydrogen with the more reactive Oxygen-16? And why, then, was it replaced by a more stable isotope, if C-12 did not possess the same property?

You should rather ask authors of the textbook, or review their own references, or directly the respective primary metrology documents.

One of ways of obtaining atomic mass is analyzing mass percentages of binary compounds where one of elements is considered as the atomic mass standard.  Reactivity of oxygen was advantage here.

I would suggest that you track down the particular standards that changed in this way, because they would always state precisely the reasons why they would be adopting such a change. Such metrology changes are always extremely well-thought-out and it is always difficult to persuade the international scientific community to adopt any changes like these.

@Poutnik Then is there a clear reason as to why C-12 was adopted, since it doesn't have the same property?

@naturallyInconsistent I did try to find them out, however I could not find many sources regarding it. The rest of your points, of course, I understand.

On of reasons for carbon-12 was reportedly solving the metrological schisma where chemists were using the scale based on natural oxygen while physicists used the scale based on oxygen-16. Carbon-12 scale sits between these 2 oxygen scales. // but there would be tons of the related metrology info on internet. // See also Dalton_(unit)

C-12 was chosen because values of the chemical scale were almost within experimental error of the chemical scale based on the natural abundance of O-16,-17,-18; which unfortunately is not constant. This meant that the chemical literature prior to the change was not obsoleted. The physical scale based on O-16 had to change substantially. Advances in mass spectrometry were constantly updating the physical scale.  Net benefit was one standard. The chemical atomic weights are still the weighted average of the isotopes present some of which are radioactive.[tritium, C-14, K-40, U]

@Poutnik  Thank you for the answer

@jimchmst Thank you for the added understanding. May I ask how and why the natural abundance of oxygen's isotopes is not constant? Because if the answer is radioactivity, that should probably hold for carbon as well?

In general the isotopic distribution of any given element is not constant around the world. There are many processes in geology that cause this.

Different isotopes have slightly different physical and chemical properties. H2O-16 has a higher VP than H2O-18 so water vapor has lower O-18 than the oceans etc. This effect is especially evident in kinetic isotope effects where bond breaking or formation to the element can have distinctly different rates for different isotopes.
